# Two Factor Authentication using Twilio in Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic2, twilio, two-factor-authentication

I was wondering if it will be possible to implement 2fa using Twilio and Ionic 2. I have tried finding tutorials but so far had no luck. If there is no way, is there any alternative? Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We haven't got a tutorial for building 2FA specifically with Ionic, however it's surely possible. I'd start by checking out our tutorial on [building 2FA with Authy](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/two-factor-authentication/node/express) and see if you can apply that to Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying this right now. And found on a forum detailed step by step instructions. Also hints about saving and configuring 2FA codes for phone #' s. I can't post a screenshot because my reputation isn't high enough yet but ill post part of the forum and gist below..it goes on a bit more with footnote links.
Good luck.

Posted by *NoGoodDeed* on  https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!starred/gmail/ErW7gPYpIaQ:

> ***...Is it possible that it is on google end do to app passwords...***
>
> Yes.
>
> Before I give some instructions and links, I want to confirm somethings.  Do you have a Gmail account?
>
> - If not: Go [1] [**HERE**](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/56256) and click on the red **CREATE AN ACCOUNT** button to get started.
>
>   - A Gmail account will end in @gmail.com, so **do not** use your own email address when creating an account.
> - If so: Go to the next question.
>
> Do you have namesilo configured to send emails to the above Gmail address?
>
> - If not: Please do so.
>
>   - Unfortunately, I can't help you with that.
> - If so: Good. Go on to the next step.
>
> With a computer, go to [mail.google.com](http://mail.google.com) and sign into (if needed) to the Gmail account that you have namesilo forwarding emails to.
>
> Then [2] [Turn On 2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744). With 2-Step, you have some more options.
>
> - I suggest that you [3] [Install Google Authenticator](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447) instead of just having a SMS or Voice call come to your phone.
> - Instead of using the official Google Authenticator app, I recommend using the [4] [Authy](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.authy.com%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGvocIXZA_wDwu7rgJ9mMNZ4IJOmw) app.
>
> The Google Authenticator and Authy apps are free & Google doesn't charge you to set up or use 2-Factor